# How to migrate an edited model after instectdb in Django Rest?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-migrations

I am completely new to Django Rest. I'm trying to build a small API to learn. In my local database I have a table named "api_task" with the following structure:

```
api_task: {
   task_id[PK],
   task_title varchar(15),
   task_description varchar(150)
}
```

I ran the command `python manage.py inspectdb api task > models.py` to include that table in the Django project. I added a field and made some changes to the model:

```
class ApiTask(models.Model):
    task_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

   def __str__(self):
       return self.title

   class Meta:
       db_table = 'api_task'
```

After that, I created the migration with `python manage.py makemigrations api`, where "api" is just the application name. When executing the migration it throws an error: `jango.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relationship already exists`. I was looking through the information on this topic and tried to run the command `python manage.py makemigrations api --fake` but the model changes are not reflected in the database. I also tried running the command `python manage.py migrate api --run-syncdb`, but it throws another error: `Cannot use run_syncdb with application 'api' as it has migrations.`

I know Django says you can't change field names or their values ​​to prevent loss of information I think, but that's not the case for me at all, I just want to update the table with the new field and new field options. Seem like something really simple to do but I don't really know what's the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can try deleting all the migrations files once and run these two commands

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: No, I tried before, but the problem is still there, thanks anyway.